# Representation of the function $(x+a)e^{-bx^2}$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

What is the graph that best represents the function  $(x+a)e^{-bx^2}$? *a* and *b* are positive constants
[Here are the options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIL9X.png)

My attempt:

At $x = 0, y=a$

Hence I eliminate the possibility of option *d*.

At $x=\pm \infty, y= 0$

Now I know the graph goes to zero at both ends.

At $x =-a, y=0$

This tells me that at a particular negative value of *x* the function goes to zero.
Then for greater negative values of *a*, the function becomes negative and it subsides to the x-axis.

Hence I choose the option *c*.

Is this how generally is it done? or are there any method to break it down to make it easier to analyze the plot?

Comment: The graph has one maximum and one minimum.  You should find those next.

Comment: @Paul You mean I should take derivative of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should next find the maximum and minimum of the function.  The derivative is $(-2bx^2-2abx+1)e^{-bx^2}$.  Setting the derivative equal to zero you see that you get an extremum at the points $$x=\frac{2ab \pm \sqrt{4a^2b^2+8b}}{4b}$$.  The negative root you can find is a minimum, and the positive root is a maximum.  This should give you what you need to graph it.